# Chargeback handling/cancelled payments in Omnipay

Tags: omnipay

Can I confirm that with gateways like Paypal IPN which are plagued by disputed payments or chargebacks that there is no mechanism within Omnipay to react to these notifications from the Gateway and nullify the payment and then take the appropriate action on the website/database?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, Omnipay doesn't have support for out of band "notifications" such as PayPal IPN *after the payment is processed*.

It correctly handles notifications when a payment is first made, but right now there aren't any methods to handle a notification in the event of a chargeback etc down the line.